# 'half' is not a member of 'Eigen'

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencl, eigen

**Task :**
I am trying to build TensorFlow Library with bazel using OpenCL in order to run the operations on GPU without enabling GPU of Tensorflow (without CUDA/NVIDIA).
Basically want to run on mobile GPU with the help of Android NDK and the built opencl-tensorflow library)

**Steps Taken:**
Replace the eigen_archive libray in /home/ashok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ashok/337a0d8d7fbaddcaa8098e349718a6d6/external with 'eigen-opencl' library of https://bitbucket.org/benoitsteiner/eigen-opencl and build TensorFlow using bazel.

**Issues Faced: 'half' is not a member of 'Eigen'**

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/ashok/Ashok/tensorflow-1.0.1/tensorflow/core/BUILD:814:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite' failed (Exit 1)
In file included from ./tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h:25:0,
from ./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h:22,
from ./tensorflow/core/util/guarded_philox_random.h:19,
from tensorflow/core/util/guarded_philox_random.cc:16:
./tensorflow/core/framework/type_traits.h:69:52: error: 'half' is not a member of 'Eigen'
std::is_trivial::value || std::is_same<T, Eigen::half>::value ||
^
./tensorflow/core/framework/type_traits.h:69:52: error: 'half' is not a member of 'Eigen'
./tensorflow/core/framework/type_traits.h:69:63: error: template argument 2 is invalid
std::is_trivial::value || std::is_same<T, Eigen::half>::value ||
^
Target //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo failed to build
```

Please help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://bitbucket.org/benoitsteiner/opencl instead of https://bitbucket.org/benoitsteiner/eigen-opencl as it is the most updated repository